# Drupal 7 - Reorder Folders in a File Browser

Tags: 7

I was looking at a way to reorder the folder structure into alphabetical order, under the "root" folder in the file browser window, of a drupal user account. I am using Drupal 7. I looked every where but couldn't find any help. Hope some body can give me an answer. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Where in Drupal are you trying to do this? Please provide a URL. For example /admin/content